# a simple limit in floor question : $\lfloor\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\rfloor$

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=-(x-1)^2+2$$
$$\lfloor\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\rfloor=?$$ 
**me & [symbolab.com](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/floor%5Cleft(%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto1%7D-%5Cleft(x-1%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%2B2%5Cright))** :

> answer is 2.

**my teacher** :

> the value of limit is not exact, so:
>   $$\lfloor\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)\rfloor = \lfloor2^-\rfloor = 1$$
>   $$\lfloor\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)\rfloor = \lfloor2^-\rfloor = 1$$
>   $$\lfloor\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\rfloor = 1$$

I don't understand that negative on 2;
who is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the floor lies *outside* the limit, and $f$ is continuous everywhere. Thus we can just evaluate $f(1)=2$ and put it into the floor function; since $2$ is an integer we just get back $2$.

The teacher thought the limit was $\lim_{x\to1}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$, which is indeed $1$.

Comment: thanks, I discussed with my teacher, but **no result!** could you give me some reference? or links to questions like this? I want something to convince my teacher.(I don't think i can!)

Comment: @aStudent Just tell the teacher that $2^-$ makes no sense.

Comment: nothing after a lot of discuss! he has a pure math degree and convincing him is too hard! anyway, if you someday seen a question like this (limit in floor) (in reference books) please tell me. maybe that convince him!

Comment: @aStudent ...I'm studying for a pure maths degree too. Don't try too hard to convince the other party.